# Postgres STRING_TO_ARRAY alternative? Like STRING_TO_RECORD?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, function

I need to convert a comma separated text into a set of records. I created this function
but I am not convinced that the best way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_StringListToRecord(pStringList TEXT, pDelimiter VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
  vIndex INT;
  arrSize INT;
  arrValue TEXT[];
BEGIN
  arrValue := STRING_TO_ARRAY(pStringList, pDelimiter);
  arrSize := ARRAY_UPPER(arrValue, 1);
  FOR vIndex IN 1..arrSize LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT arrValue[vIndex];
  END LOOP;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is there any other function similar to STRING_TO_ARRAY (perhaps STRING_TO_RECORD)?

Answer (score 4):

In 8.4 you can use:

`select * from unnest(string_to_array(my_string_here,delimiter)) as v(x);`